# What is meant by "correct term" here?

Tags: discussion

So, I ran into [this answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/6132/36823) and noticed a typo. It looked something like this:

> f So

Since this was obviously a typo, so I thought, I would correct it and suggest an edit.

So I submit the edit and than decide to look at [its edit history](https://history.stackexchange.com/posts/6132/revisions) and notice something peculiar. #4 basically put in the "typo" I had corrected and gave the following reason:

> correct term

I don't understand this. The edit when read without that context seemed seemed like a typo. Now knowing that that there was an edit specifically adding that in confuses me. The edit reason doesn't help me.

The edit was made by a user with 20k+ rep, so I would think they would know better than I, but I still don't see what is intended by the edit.

So my question comes down to this: Is edit #4 correct and it's just something I don't understand, or did the 20k+ user make a mistake?

---

EDIT: I should mention that my motivation for asking is I wouldn't want to end up participating in or starting an edit war. "Correct Term," to me makes it sound like there could be a history specific meaning that I don't know of. I would hate to "fix" it if it actually shouldn't be fixed.

Comment: Just realized it was an old question from years ago that just showed up on my home page. So maybe "edit war" was an overreaction :D.

Comment: My _guess_ would be that the person that made edit #4 changed the term, then changed their mind and made a second edit, intending to undo the change within the 3-minute window, leaving the current typo.  FWIW, I've voted to approve your edit in this case